# Force expanded state of Material-UI Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

We use Accordions to display editable entities and want to lock modified entities in the expanded state.
Currently, we are forced to lift up `expanded` state into accordion wrapper, practically duplicating built-in functionality, to prevent controlled<->uncontrolled Accordeon component transition (which is prohibited by MUI).
Something like this:

```js
const AccordionWrapper = ({isModified = false, ...otherProps}) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(isModified);

  return (
    <Accordion
      expanded={expanded}
      onChange={(_, expanded) => {
        setExpanded(expanded || isModified);
      }}
      ...otherProps
    /> );
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve it?

Alternatives we have considered:

1. `<Accordion disabled={isModified}>` + custom styles to make disabled accordion look not so disabled (grayish). This is a little daunting that there is (an unlikely) chance to lock component in a collapsed state cause we don't control it.
2. Send PR to allow controlled<->uncontrolled transition of `expanded`. In this case we could `<Accorrdion expanded={isModified ? true : undefined}>`. Actually, there is no strong **technical** problem with such transition (especially when/if https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/29237 gets merged)
3. Maybe add a new Accordion prop like "forceExpand" if MUI team will find it useful

PS. I hope MUI devs will see points 2 and 3 here on SO, cause these questions/suggestions probably are a non-issue and should not be in the MUI issue tracker.

Comment: What's wrong with the first code snippet? Why would you want to find a better way?

Comment: An additional level of indirection with custom Wrapper and duplicated state just to bypass controlled<->uncontrolled transition limitation.
I admit is not too bad, but probably it would be better for all to lift this limitation in MUI (point #2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom expand toggle on MUI Accordion then you get the same with a property:-

```
defaultExpanded={Boolean}
```

So it will be like:-

```
<Accordion defaultExpanded={true}>
{...otherProps}
</Accordon>
```